# Лишнее число в массиве

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Имею текстовый файл с неким содержимым.

В строке выделил отдельный кусок

*RUBIN1|X         100.000 m   |Y         100.000 m   |Z         100.000 m   |*

Из нее мне нужно вытянуть 3 числа (X,Y,Z). Они могут быть любыми. Для этого написал такой код

```
auto getCoords(string text,int pos) {
string str;
char i = text[pos];
while (i != '\n'){
    str.push_back(i);
    i = text[++pos];
}
regex words_regex("[+-]?\\d+\\.?\\d*");
auto words_begin = sregex_iterator(str.begin(), str.end(), words_regex);
auto words_end = sregex_iterator();
size_t size = distance(words_begin, words_end);
double* arr = new double[size];

double* it2 = arr;
for (sregex_iterator it = words_begin; it != words_end; ++it) {
    *it2 = stod(it->str());
    ++it2;
}

return arr;
delete[] arr;
```

*где **text**- строка с текстом из файла, **pos** - позиция | после **слова** RUBIN1*

Для вывода содержимого на экран использую:

```
for (auto i = 0; i < sizeof(arr); ++i)
            cout << arr[i] << " ";
```

Однако в консоли получаю:

```
100 100 100 1.10195е-309
```

Не могу понять, откуда берётся четвёртое число

Comment: `arr` - это указатель, `sizeof(arr);` возвращает количество байт, занимаемое указателем

Comment: `sizeof(arr)` в вашем случае - вообще-то просто размер указателя на `double`...

Comment: Как в таком случае обращаться к элементам массива?

Comment: а вы возвращайте и размер массива тоже: return std::make_pair( arr, size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof(arr)` в вашем случае - вообще-то просто размер указателя на `double`...

У вас столько разных классов C++ - и `regex`, и итераторы... что вам стоит сделать

```
vector<double> arr;
...
for (sregex_iterator it = words_begin; it != words_end; ++it) {
    arr.push_back(stod(it->str()));
}
...


for (auto i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i)
    cout << arr[i] << " ";
```